# Trouble integrating

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra

I'm having trouble getting started on an analysis problem:

Let $f(x,y)$ be continuously differentiable.

We are to show that

$$f(x,y)=\int_{0}^{1}(x,y) \cdot \nabla f(tx,ty)t \ dt + \int_{0}^{1} f(tx,ty)dt.$$

I'm sure this is relatively straightforward, but I'm having a bit of a block.

Any hints - like how to unpack $\nabla f$, for example - would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$f(x,y) = tf(tx,ty)\bigg|_{t = 0}^1 = \int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial t}[tf(tx,ty)]\, dt$$

Now use the product rule and chain rule to finish.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you.